# Number of unique permutations of letters

Tags: permutations

Let's say there are 7 available letters: `ABCDEFG`, and I would like to calculate the number of unique 5 letter combinations that can be made, e.g. `AABBE`. Double letters are perfectly fine, the only thing is that the order doesn't matter, so `AABBA` and `ABAAB` are regarded as the same and are counted only once.

I think the binomial theorem can be used when none of the letters are to be repeated, but I'm a bit stuck on adding the permutations where a letters is used more than once.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{1},x_{2},...x_{7}$ denote the number of letter $A,B,C,...,G$ respectively. We need to find non - negative integer solution of $\sum_{i=1}^{7}{x_{i}}=5$.

This is stars and bars problem with solution $\binom{11}{6}$